# Does $u \in W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$ imply $|u| \in W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$?

Tags: analysis, sobolev-spaces

Is the mentioned implication valid? On the first look, of course, but I've got no clue how to prove it. I guess we also may assume, that the trace-operator exists. Thanks, FFoDWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a chain rule for weak derivatives; someone on this site recommends Evans and Gariepy as a reference: [How to prove the chain rule with respect to weak derivatives?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128201/how-to-prove-the-chain-rule-with-respect-to-weak-derivatives)

**EDIT: The below argument is wrong - see comments.**

Define $F_\epsilon(t)=\sqrt{t^2+\epsilon^2}-\epsilon.$ For smooth $u$, the usual chain rule shows that $u_\epsilon=F(u)$ is in $W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$ with weak derivatives $D_iu_\epsilon=F_\epsilon'(u)D_iu,$ which converge in $L^2$ to $\operatorname{sgn}(u)D_iu$ by dominated convergence (taking $\operatorname{sgn}(0)=0$). Note $\|\operatorname{sgn}(u)D_iu\|_2\leq \|D_iu\|_2.$ (Presumably they're actually equal, though I think that would take more work to show.) Since $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ is dense in $W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$, this proves that the map $u\mapsto |u|$ extends to a $1$-Lipschitz operator on $W^{1,2}_0(\Omega).$

Comment: I cannot agree with your last sentence. $u \mapsto |u|$ is continuous on $H_0^1(\Omega)$, but it is not Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: @gerw: thanks, I need to learn to be more careful with non-linear operators. I don't actually see a good way to show $u\mapsto |u|$ is continuous at the moment..

Comment: This can be shown by DCT: if $u_n \to u$ in $H_0^1$, then $\nabla |u_n| \to \nabla |u|$ pointwise a.e. and $|u|$ is also a square-integrable upper bound. Hence, $\nabla |u_n| \to \nabla |u|$ in $L^2(\Omega)$.